# Convert X25519 raw binary key to pem file for openssl

Tags: python, c, openssl, pem, x25519

I have a binary file with one x25519 public key (raw format). I am looking for a way to create a pem (asn.1) to pass to openssl.
C or python solutions would be fine too.
Any advise?

Comment: OpenSSL command-line utilities, or an OpenSSL-based custom application?  And your raw-formatted key is probably already in ASN.1 format, and can probably already be read by OpenSSL using the DER format option.  See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ec.html and https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/asn1parse.html

Comment: My raw formatted key is not in asn.1 format. Just a byte sequence. It is generated elsewhere and saved in a file.